# SQL: Many to Many to a Many to Many... is this efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

thanks in advance for your input.

I have 3 objects:

- School
- Camp
- Coach

With the following relationships:

- A School can have multiple Camps.
- A School can have multiple Coaches.
- A Camp can have multiple Schools.
- A Camp can have multiple Coaches.
- A Coach can have multiple Schools.
- A Coach can have multiple Camps.

A many to many, School_Camp, obviously links a School to a Camp with an additional field for Date, to identify the year of the camp. But one camp can have multiple coaches.

::School_Camp::

- School_id
- Camp_id
- Date

Would it be better for me to set up another many to many, School_Camp_Coach, that links to the School_Camp and Coach tables?

::School_Camp_Coach::

- School_Camp_id
- Coach_id

If this is the more efficient way to do this... should I give School_Camp an independent id column that can quickly be referenced rather than using the three fields as an identifier?

::School_Camp::

- id*
- School_id
- Camp_id
- Date

**OR**

Is it better to just have ONE many to many table, School_Camp_Coach, with 3 foreign keys?

::School_Camp_Coach::

- School_id
- Camp_id
- Coach_id
- Date

The only issue I foresee with this, is that you'll have multiple entries for the foreign keys, but with different Dates.

Thanks again.

Comment: At least use captial letters when thanking in advance?

Comment: Most efficient with respect to what? Data storage size? Retrieval or update times? Query complexity? For some measures of efficiency, it depends on what you are going to do with the data. Sometimes it pays to denormalize; other times it doesn't.

Comment: Data storage size and Query complexity are the more important factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a matter of efficiency, it is a matter of correctness: the two options that you presented do not *model* the same relationship between the records in the tables.

Each record in the database means something. If the meaning of the record in the junction table is "X coached at the camp Y of the school Z", then you should go with the option 2; if you are looking to model the meanings "X coached at the camp Y" independently of "X coached for school Z" and independently of "School Z ran camp Y", then you should go with option 1.

In both cases you should give your junction records independent primary keys, rather than relying on three-way combination of IDs: it will simplify your life when you implement code that applies corrections to the junction table.

Comment: great answer... and makes complete sense now. Thank you!

Comment: The best way to describe the relationships:
CoachX is the *current coach for SchoolY. CoachX hosted CampZ 3 years ago and this year for their *current SchoolY. 

*If CoachX switches to another SchoolY, and hosts another CampZ... the relationship between the previous CampZ and SchoolY for the CoachX remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

See @Ted Hopp's comment.

Given the data (school camps don't occur many times a minute), I'd think that update times are less of a priority than retrieval times. If that is true, I'd go with your last option, 3 foreign keys.

This would be an example of a [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Comment: I didn't think about update or retrieval times. I was still just trying to design the database... thanks for giving me insight into another factor that should be included in database design.

Answer (score 0):

The `Coach` entity to me looks like one that should have what I usually call a `basket` where it can be linked with other entities in a many to many relationship. Here's how I mean:

```
# The coach model
CREATE TABLE coach(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    name VARCHAR(20),
    capacity INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

# The coach data - who is using the coaches
CREATE TABLE coach_basket(
    coach_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(coach_id) REFERENCES coach(id),
    entity_id INT, /* the school or camp id */
    entity_type ENUM("School","Camp"),
    fromdate DATETIME,
    todate DATETIME
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So now you can keep track of all the coach usages, just enter the entity_id (school or camp id), and the date and times they used them, every time they use a coach.

You need a similar type of table to store which schools and camps are connected, it can look like this:

```
# Store school-camp connections
CREATE TABLE connections(
    school_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(school_id) REFERENCES school(id),
    camp_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(camp_id) REFERENCES camp(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Very simple, just hold school and camp id's, so if you query a school_id you get many camps that the school is associated with, and visa versa.

All what is left is your `school` and `camp` tables, which are models (like the coach table at the top).

Comment: I've never seen the basket before. Interesting approach. Thank you.